# dereferencing pointer to incomplete type in structures

Tags: pointers, structure, lex, extern

I went through other posts regarding this but nothing like my problem.
I am trying to access a structure from one file(1.l). Show below is my declaration and definition of my structure in the file 1.l.

<1.l>

```
struct node
{
char words[50];
struct node *next;
};

struct node *head = NULL;
struct node *head1 = NULL;
```

The file from which I am trying to access is 2.l. 2.l is shown below.

```
%{

#include "y.tab.h"
extern struct node *head1;

%}

%x SECTION

%%

"#pragma omp section"   { BEGIN SECTION; yyless(0); }

<SECTION>"#pragma omp section"  {
                                fprintf(yyout,"meta_fork");
                                while(head1 != NULL)
                                {
   \\error in this line         fprintf(yyout,"shared(%s)",head1->words);
   \\error in this line         head1 = head1->next;
                                }
                                }
%%
```

The error is dereferencing pointer to incomplete type.

Can anyone please tell me what's the problem here. Thanks.

Comment: I also tried defining my stuct *head1 like below but still getting the same error.

struct node *head1
{
char words[50];
struct node *next;
};

Answer (score 1):

Unless the definition of `struct node` appears in <2.l>, the compiler won't know what members it has. You should move the definition to a header file, then include it in both lex files.

Comment: Thank you. So you mean the definition has to be in both the files?? I have to access the things that have been saved in head1 of 1.l. Can I do it?

Comment: I defined struct node definition and put that in a header file and then tried. It says, undefined reference to `head1'. Please help.

Comment: I fixed it by declaring head and head1 in the header file rather in 1.l. Thanks @DreW.

Comment: Did you declare it with `extern`? If not, you'll run into link errors later

Comment: I didn't declare it as extern in my header file. Do I have to? I did declare it as extern in my 1.l and 2.l. Thanks

Comment: I am not able to access the variables in head1 from 2.l.